# How to change sign text color in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have gone through every single website and video to try to make a sign with colored text, but nothing works. Can anyone help me to get a sign to say:

> Place Block(dark blue and bold text)

I really want this for a map I am making and I need help.

Answer (score 7):

**What to use**

It is common to use `/blockdata` for changing placed sign data. So, we will use it for now. The syntax of `/blockdata` is `/blockdata [x] [y] [z] [dataInJSON]` . Note that we use JSON formatting for text.

**Basic for sign**

To input a text with `/blockdata`, we will use `Text1` tag. To write "Hello World" into the first line of the sign, simply just do `/blockdata [x] [y] [z] {Text1:"{\"text\":\"Hello World\"}"}`. The quotes is there for JSON formatting.
If you need multiple line to display, use either `Text2`, `Text3` or `Text4`.

**Coloring**

There is a way to change color of the sign using the `color` sub tag. There is a lot selection of color. Here is all of the available one:

- gold
- red
- dark_red
- yellow
- dark_purple
- light_purple
- aqua
- dark_aqua
- black
- white
- green
- dark_green
- blue
- dark_blue

For writing "Hello World" in aqua, you write

`/blockdata [x] [y] [z] {Text1:"{\"text\":\"Hello World\",\"color\":\"aqua\"}"}`

into a command block. It will change the sign with the first line saying "Hello World" on aqua.

**Bold**

For bold text, you use `bold` sub-tag. This sub-tag is a boolean, meaning the value can be only `true` or `false` for example:

`/blockdata [x] [y] [z] {Text1:"{\"text\":\"Hello World\",\"bold\":true}"}`

will give you a sign with text "Hello World" with bold.

**The real answer**

Type this into a command block changing [x], [y], and [z] into the coords of the sign:

`/blockdata [x] [y] [z] {Text1:"{\"text\":\"Place Block\",\"color\":\"dark_blue\",\"bold\":true}"}`

[Full list for Raw JSON tags](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#Raw_JSON_text)

Comment: You can also use `/setblock` with the same NBT and JSON format. Note that it erases any existing text.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `/give` command too.

by using the `BlockEntityTag` You can place a sign down with text.

for example if I wanted a sign with "RedIsCool" with red color I would have to do

```
/give @p sign 1 0 {BlockEntityTag:{Text2:"{\"text\":\"RedIsCool\",\"color\":\"red\"}"}}
```

in a command block, and then power it.

Answer (score 1):

## Version Update

### 1.12−

Above answers apply.

### 1.13

1.13 changed the command syntax. NBT now goes directly after the block/item ID, without a space. Here are some updated 1.13 commands from the previous answers:

```
/give @p sign{BlockEntityTag:{Text2:"{\"text\":\"RedIsCool\",\"color\":\"red\"}"}} 1
/setblock ~ ~ ~ sign{Text2:"{\"text\":\"RedIsCool\",\"color\":\"red\"}"}}
```

In addition, [`/blockdata`](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/blockdata) is now a deprecated command, and has been replaced by `/data merge block`. Run the following command to change placed block data:

```
/data merge block ~ ~ ~ {Text1:"{\"text\":\"RedIsCool\",\"color\":\"red\"}"}
```

### 1.14+

The 1.13 commands still work in 1.14+, but additional modifications are possible to make the commands easier to read:

- You can use `/data modify` instead of `/data merge`. This allows you to modify one specific tag at a time. This is more useful when performing complex operations with NBT tags, but isn't really needed for simple operations.
- 1.14 added support for single quotes `'` to surround NBT string tags instead of double quotes `"`. Therefore, you can make the following replacement:

  ```
  {Text1:"{\"text\":\"RedIsCool\",\"color\":\"red\"}"}
  {Text1:'{"text":"RedIsCool","color":"red"}'}
  ```

which will make it much easier to read.

Comment: @Niekvb Hi, I noticed that you posted a new question related to this, and then followed-up with a self-answer. Are you still having problems?

Answer (score 1):

It is example sign with custom text color:

```
/give @p oak_sign{BlockEntityTag:{Text1:'{"text":"Example","color":"#123456"}'}}
```

#123456 is your color hex. You can convert RGB to color hex with [this](https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/color/rgb-to-hex.html) website.

(RGB is Red Green Blue)